# Undeletion Request

Tags: discussion, undelete-request

I was hoping that I could get [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/298181) question about an audio issue in [thief](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thief)  undeleted. At the time I hadn't gotten any answers so I decided to play another game instead, but recently I wanted to pick up the game again and went to bounty the question, but it had been Roomba'd. Could I get a few undelete votes on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone ahead and undeleted this. In the future I'd suggest just using a moderator flag instead.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks :)